# создание вкладок с перелистыванием из одного объекта массива

Tags: android

В книге "Head First Программирование для андроид" в приложении Starbuzz после двух активити со списковыми представлениями на основе полученного объекта строится последняя активность с детальным описанием кофе: название, фото и описание. Нужно вместо последней активности сделать 3 вкладки с горизонтальной прокруткой - в одной название кофе, в другой фото, в 3-й описание. Как это сделать?

Comment: Чувствую себя глупым. Ничего не понял.

Comment: раскройте свою задачу так, чтобы она стала понятной не только вам, но и тем, кто бы хотел вам помочь решить вашу проблему

Comment: Например, в книге "Head First Программирование для андроид" в приложении Starbuzz после двух активити со списковыми представлениями на основе полученного объекта строится последняя активность с детальным описанием кофе: название, фото и описание. Нужно вместо  последней активности сделать 3 вкладки с горизонтальной прокруткой - в одной название кофе, в другой фото в 3-й описание. Как это сделать?

Comment: вносите дополнения в сам вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не в комментариях к нему